# Error: (416) Requested Range Not Satisfiable.on POST Request

Tags: c#, http, post, http-headers, fiddler

I guys, i need to make a POST request but i been rejected with a `Remote server Error: (416) Requested Range Not Satisfiable.` with a request structured like this:

```
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.Host = "launches-api.endclothing.com";
            req.KeepAlive = true;
            req.ContentLength = sentData.Length;
            req.Accept = "application/json, text/plain, */*";
            req.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
            req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36";
            req.Headers["Origin"] = "https://launches.endclothing.com";

            req.Headers["Sec-Fetch-Site"] = "same-site";
            req.Headers["Sec-Fetch-Mode"] = "cors";
            req.Headers["Sec-Fetch-Dest"] = "empty";
            req.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "https://launches.endclothing.com";

            req.Referer = "https://launches.endclothing.com/";
            req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip, deflate, br";
            req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7";
```

The original POST request sniffed from Fiddler got some extra-headers which change at every request and them are mentioned in the OPTIONS package sent before making the request.
[Fiddler POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNQLr.png)
[OPTIONS package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxGwE.png)

So i don't know where to take that Headers i am missing in my request.
Can you please give me a tip?

Comment: This link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/416#:~:text=The%20HyperText%20Transfer%20Protocol%20(HTTP,%2C%20doesn't%20make%20sense. may be of help?

Comment: Using images in your question is not recommended, see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: To the actual question, you should look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Request-Method) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Request-Headers) to find out more about those "extra-headers which change at every request"

Comment: First of all thank you for yours reply! I am stucked on this from a week :(
@Expolarity thanks for the tip which will help me writing better my future questions. For the problem i have tried to add:
req.Headers["Access-Control-Request-Method"] = "POST";
req.Headers["Access-Control-Request-Headers"] = "content-type,exj5wzxnuf-a,exj5wzxnuf-b,exj5wzxnuf-c,exj5wzxnuf-d,exj5wzxnuf-f,exj5wzxnuf-z";
But nothing change... Do you have any other idea?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ i know what the formal 416 error is, but is not my case.... Do you have other ideas?

Comment: What are you using to send the request? From looking at the code you provided, is it `HttpWebRequest` from `System.Net`?.The extra headers are maybe for some kind of authentication? (I never encountered the 2 access control headers so I don't know the purpose of them) They might be what causes the 416 code, the servers are not required to follow the specification and can raise any status code whenever they want

Comment: Maybe all the `exj5WzXnUF` are a kind of authentication token, also because all of them change at every request even of the same type. Can maybe them be provided from a sort of JS code inside the page? Do you think this can be possible or maybe them are sended from the server in a way that i am missing? Possible with the Cors request?

Comment: BTW you are right, i am using HttpWebRequest with C# code from System.Net